# How to upload image on server using Unirest library

Tags: java, android, unirest

I am uploading image on server using Unirest library, but getting error like

```
{"code":400,"message":"Unknown content type [contentType=application/octet-stream]"}
```

My code is

```
 Unirest.post(url).header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")                     .header("x-mysolomeo-session-key", "77e02e5c-bdac-4906-bb6c-90c6001b75a3.2017-03-03T17:15:10.101Z").field("token", "77e02e5c-bdac-4906-bb6c-90c6001b75a3")                     .field("documentType","Picture ID").field("documentImage", new File(new URI("file:///storage/emulated/0/logo.png"))).asString()
```

Can anyone help me on this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are another also cool rest libraries. As for me i didn't hear your before. Look at okhttp, retrofit and so on

Comment: I used okhttp library also but I am getting the same error.

Comment: if you get the same error check server side code. So it is strange

Answer (score 0):

I upload files using Unirest in Java roughly like this:

```
    File file =  somefile;
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    final HttpResponse<String> stringHttpResponse = Unirest.put("Your Url")
        .header("Content-Type", mediaType)
        .body(data)
        .asString();
    if (stringHttpResponse.getStatus() != 200)
    {
        // error
    }
```